The pipeline failed due to the user not being verified
I build a automated changelog Here is the link to the HowTO https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2023/11/01/tutorial-automated-release-and-release-notes-with-gitlab/. The pipelines for the prepare-job and release-job run without errors. The error message is: The pipeline failed due to the user not being verified. What means this error message and how do I solve this error? The CI_API_TOKEN pushes the new CHANGELOG.md to GitLab Pages. It worked for days. Okay I have tested a lot, so I made about 200 commits in one week. Maybe I'm locked out of GitLab. Maybe an error has crept in due to repeated installation and configuration? This Project is build by Hugo.
I made a lot of screenshots: please take a lot of them:

I have created a CI_API_TOKEN



